# How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" (ordinal indicator)?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, ordinal

I know this will give me the day of the month as a number (`11`, `21`, `23`):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDayOfMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
```

But how do you format the day of the month to include an [ordinal indicator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator), say `11th`, `21st` or `23rd`?

Comment: For reference these are called ordinal numbers - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics).

Comment: Just for the record, anything constructing the response instead of looking up the _whole_ answer in a table is close to impossible to localize to other languages.

Comment: The answer is somehow incorrect have a look at my answer plz.

Comment: Modern comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Take a look at the numbers API (https://math.tools/api/numbers/). It has support for ordinal, cardinal , number spelled out in different language, spelled out as currency in various languages etc.

Comment: @OleV.V. java.time is not supported in android

Comment: Oh yes, @Ssenyonjo, java.time is supported on Android alright. From Android API level 26 it is built in. For lower API levels it’s available through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: I think this post will help you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816360/12883809](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816360/12883809)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

```
// https://github.com/google/guava
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;

String getDayOfMonthSuffix(final int n) {
    checkArgument(n >= 1 && n <= 31, "illegal day of month: " + n);
    if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (n % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

The table from @kaliatech is nice, but since the same information is repeated, it opens the chance for a bug. Such a bug actually exists in the table for `7tn`, `17tn`, and `27tn` (this bug might get fixed as time goes on because of the fluid nature of StackOverflow, so check [the version history on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4011116/revisions) to see the error).

Comment: Yeah, but @kaliatech can fix his table whereas your algorithm cannot be adjusted to correctly handle the 11th, 12th and 13th of the month.

Comment: it really feels like an oversight in the simple data format, doesn't it?

Comment: @J888 The ordinal-suffix style is hardcoded, but that's exactly the context of this question.

Comment: Have fun internationalising this. :D

Comment: @Trejkaz Outside of the scope of the question :)

Comment: @GregMattes who said it was in scope? It's something which always comes up eventually. (If the software is decent.)

Comment: This answer needs to be downvoted to oblivion-  it will horribly fail in any language other than english

Comment: What if we want to do this for a different locale ?

Comment: Chuck Norris can check bounds of an argument without `Preconditions.`

Comment: This solution supports only English. Use RuleBasedNumberFormat from  ICU4J for the localized solution.

Comment: @Trejkaz and the _this cannot be internationalized_ crowd in general, how does one "internationalize this"? There is going to be a different _algorithm_ for almost every language anyway. Why having to rewrite the algo for the new language is significantly worse than having to create the table for the new language? Can you clarify (better if with an example) the disadvantages that you are considering?

Comment: @SantiBailors In this particular case, I think CLDR has already built the tables for a large number of languages, so the effort required to build the table itself is zero. The table more or less contains algorithms though, if you look at it, so it essentially comes down to implementing parsing of that expression language. I'm fairly sure ICU will already have that job done, so my own preference would be to use ICU.

Comment: @Trejkaz I too would go for existing standards / libraries, but your comment meant that this solution was bad in absolute, not that it was just worse than some other one (none was mentioned anyway). No already existing alternative was mentioned, that's why I wondered why it's better to have to create a new table instead of a new algorithm (which I think is not).

Comment: You guys are off in the weeds, and the tone is taking a bit of turn. No need for that.

This question didn't ask about the intricacies of internationalization. Internationalization is certainly a fine topic to discuss, but it should be done on another question with that focus. I've always interpreted this question as asking for a quick and dirty way to accomplish this in English.

So, I suggest that if there's really no good solution in the Java world that is internationalization friendly that we start a project on, e.g., GitHub and create a good solution. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: @GregMattes I am interested

Comment: @Ssenyonjo post a link to the repos.

Answer (score 60):

There is nothing in JDK to do this.

```
  static String[] suffixes =
  //    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
       "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
       "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    30    31
       "th", "st" };

 Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat formatDayOfMonth  = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
 int day = Integer.parseInt(formatDateOfMonth.format(date));
 String dayStr = day + suffixes[day];
```

Or using Calendar:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(date);
 int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 String dayStr = day + suffixes[day];
```

Per comments by @thorbjørn-ravn-andersen, a table like this can be helpful when localizing:

```
  static String[] suffixes =
     {  "0th",  "1st",  "2nd",  "3rd",  "4th",  "5th",  "6th",  "7th",  "8th",  "9th",
       "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", "19th",
       "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th",
       "30th", "31st" };
```

Comment: If you let the table contain the full "21st", "23rd", "29th" it can be externalized and localized to other languages.  For successful software that may become a requirement.

Answer (score 45):

```
private String getCurrentDateInSpecificFormat(Calendar currentCalDate) {
    String dayNumberSuffix = getDayNumberSuffix(currentCalDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" d'" + dayNumberSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(currentCalDate.getTime());
}

private String getDayNumberSuffix(int day) {
    if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (day % 10) {
    case 1:
        return "st";
    case 2:
        return "nd";
    case 3:
        return "rd";
    default:
        return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution while omitting the single quotes in the pattern string provided to the SimpleDateFormat constructor. I now see why they're there. I'm getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` because of "an illegal pattern character, t."

Answer (score 35):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. The `SimpleDateFormat` class was OK to use when the question was asked 8 years ago, but you should avoid it now as it is not only long outdated, but also notoriously troublesome. Use `java.time` instead.

**Edit**

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText(TemporalField, Map<Long, String>)` is great for this purpose. Using it we build a formatter that does the work for us:

```
    Map<Long, String> ordinalNumbers = new HashMap<>(42);
    ordinalNumbers.put(1L, "1st");
    ordinalNumbers.put(2L, "2nd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(3L, "3rd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(21L, "21st");
    ordinalNumbers.put(22L, "22nd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(23L, "23rd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(31L, "31st");
    for (long d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
        ordinalNumbers.putIfAbsent(d, "" + d + "th");
    }

    DateTimeFormatter dayOfMonthFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ordinalNumbers)
            .appendPattern(" MMMM")
            .toFormatter();

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.AUGUST, 30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(date.format(dayOfMonthFormatter));
        date = date.plusDays(1);
    }
```

The output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 30th August
> 31st August
> 1st September
> 2nd September
> 3rd September
> 4th September
> ```

**Old answer**

This code is shorter, but IMHO not so elegant.

```
    // ordinal indicators by numbers (1-based, cell 0 is wasted)
    String[] ordinalIndicators = new String[31 + 1];
    Arrays.fill(ordinalIndicators, 1, ordinalIndicators.length, "th");
    ordinalIndicators[1] = ordinalIndicators[21] = ordinalIndicators[31] = "st";
    ordinalIndicators[2] = ordinalIndicators[22] = "nd";
    ordinalIndicators[3] = ordinalIndicators[23] = "rd";

    DateTimeFormatter dayOfMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d");

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Menominee")).plusWeeks(1);
    System.out.println(today.format(dayOfMonthFormatter) 
                        + ordinalIndicators[today.getDayOfMonth()]);
```

Running this snippet just now I got

> 23rd

One of the many features of `java.time` is that it’s straightforward and reliable to get the day of month as an `int`, which is obviously needed for picking the right suffix from the table.

I recommend you write a unit test too.

**PS** A similar formatter can also be used for *parsing* a date string containing ordinal numbers like `1st`, `2nd`, etc. That was done in [this question: *Java - Parse date with optional seconds*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799175/java-parse-date-with-optional-seconds).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Would love to get this answer bumped up higher as this more modern answer is better than trying to roll your own implementation.

Answer (score 19):

```
String ordinal(int num)
{
    String[] suffix = {"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};
    int m = num % 100;
    return String.valueOf(num) + suffix[(m > 3 && m < 21) ? 0 : (m % 10)];
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Question is little old. As this question is very noisy so posting what I did solved with static method as a util. Just copy, paste and use it!

```
 public static String getFormattedDate(Date date){
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            //2nd of march 2015
            int day=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

            if(!((day>10) && (day<19)))
            switch (day % 10) {
            case 1:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'st' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            case 2:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'nd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            case 3:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'rd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            default: 
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
    }
```

**For testing purose**

Example: calling it from main method!

```
Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
          System.out.println(getFormattedDate(cal.getTime()));
          cal.set(Calendar.DATE,(cal.getTime().getDate()+1));
        }
```

Output:

```
22nd of February 2018
23rd of February 2018
24th of February 2018
25th of February 2018
26th of February 2018
27th of February 2018
28th of February 2018
1st of March 2018
2nd of March 2018
3rd of March 2018
4th of March 2018
5th of March 2018
6th of March 2018
7th of March 2018
8th of March 2018
9th of March 2018
10th of March 2018
11th of March 2018
12th of March 2018
13th of March 2018
14th of March 2018
15th of March 2018
16th of March 2018
17th of March 2018
18th of March 2018
19th of March 2018
20th of March 2018
21st of March 2018
22nd of March 2018
23rd of March 2018
24th of March 2018
25th of March 2018
```

Answer (score 9):

If you try to be aware of i18n the solution get even more complicated.

The problem is that in other languages the suffix may depend not only on the number itself, but also on the noun it counts. For example in Russian it would be "2-ой день", but "2-ая неделя" (these mean "2nd day", but "2nd week"). This is not apply if we formatting only days, but in a bit more generic case you should be aware of complexity.

I think nice solution (I didn't have time to actually implement) would be to extend SimpleDateFormetter to apply Locale-aware MessageFormat before passing to the parent class. This way you would be able to support let say for March formats %M to get "3-rd", %MM to get "03-rd" and %MMM to get "third". From outside this class looks like regular SimpleDateFormatter, but supports more formats. Also if this pattern would be by mistake applied by regular SimpleDateFormetter the result would be incorrectly formatted, but still readable.

Comment: Good point about genders in Russian, but that would technically make %MMM impossible without additional context.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, this is not true as %MMM will be applied to month, so we know the noun to conjugate.

Answer (score 8):

Many of the examples here will not work for 11, 12, 13. This is more generic and will work for all case.

```
switch (date) {
                case 1:
                case 21:
                case 31:
                    return "" + date + "st";

                case 2:
                case 22:
                    return "" + date + "nd";

                case 3:
                case 23:
                    return "" + date + "rd";

                default:
                    return "" + date + "th";
}
```

Comment: Works really well and simple too, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package and the newer Java switch statement, the following easily allows an ordinal to be placed on a day of the month.  One drawback is that this does not lend itself to canned formats specified in the [DateFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Simply create a day of some format but include `%s%s` to add the day and ordinal later.

```
ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.now();
String format = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM '%s%s,' yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz"));
```

Now pass the day of the week and the just formatted date to a helper method to add the ordinal day.

```
int day = ldt.getDayOfMonth();
System.out.println(applyOrdinalDaySuffix(format, day));
```

Prints

```
Tuesday, October 6th, 2020 11:38:23 AM EDT
```

Here is the helper method.

Using the `Java 14` [switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) makes getting the ordinal very easy.

```
public static String applyOrdinalDaySuffix(String format,
        int day) {
    if (day < 1 || day > 31)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Bad day of month (%s)", day));
    String ord = switch (day) {
        case 1, 21, 31 -> "st";
        case 2, 22 -> "nd";
        case 3, 23 -> "rd";
        default -> "th";
    };
    
    return String.format(format, day, ord);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## `RuleBasedNumberFormat` in ICU library

I appreciated the link to the ICU project's library from @Pierre-Olivier Dybman (http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html), however still had to figure out how to use it, so an example of the `RuleBasedNumberFormat` usage is below.

It will only format single number rather than the whole date, so you will need to build a combined string if looking for a date in format: Monday 3rd February, for example.

The below code sets up the `RuleBasedNumberFormat` as an Ordinal format for a given Locale, creates a `java.time ZonedDateTime`, and then formats the number with its ordinal into a string.

```
RuleBasedNumberFormat numOrdinalFormat = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.UK,
    RuleBasedNumberFormat.ORDINAL);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland"));

String dayNumAndOrdinal = numOrdinalFormat.format(zdt.toLocalDate().getDayOfMonth());
```

Example output:

> 3rd

Or

> 4th

etc.

Answer (score 5):

I can't be satisfied by the answers calling for a English-only solution based on manual formats. I've been looking for a proper solution for a while now and I finally found it.

You should be using [RuleBasedNumberFormat](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html). It works perfectly and it's respectful of the Locale.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler and sure way of doing this.  The function you'll need to use is getDateFromDateString(dateString);  It basically removes the st/nd/rd/th off of a date string and simply parses it.  You can change your SimpleDateFormat to anything and this will work.

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
public static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)");

private static Date getDateFromDateString(String dateString) throws ParseException {
     return sdf.parse(deleteOrdinal(dateString));
}

private static String deleteOrdinal(String dateString) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dateString);
    while (m.find()) {
        dateString = dateString.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group(0)), m.group(1));
    }
    return dateString;
```

}

Comment: This Answer is about *parsing* a String while the Question is about *generating* a String. But still appropriate as one is likely to need both directions. Also, this Answer solves [this other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33389982/642706).

Answer (score 3):

Only issue with the solution provided by Greg is that it does not account for number greater than 100 with the "teen" numbers ending.  For example, 111 should be 111th, not 111st.  This is my solution:

```
/**
 * Return ordinal suffix (e.g. 'st', 'nd', 'rd', or 'th') for a given number
 * 
 * @param value
 *           a number
 * @return Ordinal suffix for the given number
 */
public static String getOrdinalSuffix( int value )
{
    int hunRem = value % 100;
    int tenRem = value % 10;

    if ( hunRem - tenRem == 10 )
    {
        return "th";
    }
    switch ( tenRem )
    {
    case 1:
        return "st";
    case 2:
        return "nd";
    case 3:
        return "rd";
    default:
        return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: In what case would a Day Month sequence have more than 31 days??

Comment: @SatanEnglish, the good thing about this static factory method is that it can be used for more than just getting the suffix of a month. :)

Comment: This method returns st for 11, nd for 12 and rd for 13

Comment: @SatanEnglish. Given that today is Febrember 137th in my calendar of choice, I think your question answers itself. Seriously though, non-Gregorian calendars abound if you know where to look.

Comment: No,@TheIT, it does not. I tested. It returns `th` for 11, 12 and 13 as it should. I believe the `if ( hunRem - tenRem == 10 )` case makes sure it does.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my self a helper method to get patterns for this.

```
public static String getPattern(int month) {
    String first = "MMMM dd";
    String last = ", yyyy";
    String pos = (month == 1 || month == 21 || month == 31) ? "'st'" : (month == 2 || month == 22) ? "'nd'" : (month == 3 || month == 23) ? "'rd'" : "'th'";
    return first + pos + last;
}
```

and then we can call it as

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();//For reference
int month = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getPattern(month));
String date = localDate.format(formatter);
System.out.println(date);
```

the output is

```
December 12th, 2018
```

Comment: This requires a minimum API of 26 though :)

Comment: @MikkelLarsen this question wasn't about android, I was using Java 8 for this. Android doesn't support a large api for java 8.

Comment: @SamSakerz my bad :)

Comment: @MikkelLarsen Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

Try below function:

```
public static String getFormattedDate(Date date) 
{
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  //2nd of march 2015
  int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
  if (!((day > 10) && (day < 19)))
   switch (day % 10) {
    case 1:
     return new SimpleDateFormat("d'st' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
    case 2:
     return new SimpleDateFormat("d'nd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
    case 3:
     return new SimpleDateFormat("d'rd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
    default:
     return new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
   }
  return new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I recommend we don’t use `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also I’m in doubt what new your answer contributes compared to the other 18 answers?

Comment: For 12thi, it will print "12nd" which is incorrect. Similarly for 13th

Answer (score 2):

**For Kotlin try this**

```
fun Int.ordinalAbbrev() =
        if (this % 100 / 10 == 1) "th"
        else when (this % 10) { 1 -> "st" 2 -> "nd" 3 -> "rd" else -> "th" }
```

it takes int value and returns like this **'3rd' '1st' '11th' '2nd'**.
So you can use it for date format also.

**Usage**

```
fun getFormatedDate(date: String): String {
        date.let {
            try {
                val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
                val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", Locale.getDefault())
                val dateArray = formatter.format(parser.parse(it)).split(" ").toTypedArray()
                val formatedDate = String.format(
                    "${dateArray[0]}${
                        dateArray[0].toInt().ordinalAbbrev()
                    } ${dateArray[1]}"
                )

                return formatedDate
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return date
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you noticed - the OP was in Java?  And has been aanswered 21 times.  What does you answer offer that the others didn't?

Comment: I don't know about others. but my answer is for kotlin developers and it is more helpfull.

Comment: Could you update the answer @AzizEjaz to mention Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String getReadableDate(final int date){
    String suffix = "th";
    switch (date){
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            suffix = "st";
            break;
        case 2:
        case 22:
            suffix = "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
        case 23:
            suffix = "rd";
            break;
    }
    return date + suffix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Is there any essential difference from [the existing asnwer by sivag 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528293/5772882)?

Comment: Hey @OleV.V. No, there's no fundamental difference as such. However I felt this to be cleaner and understandable better. But that can be my perspective. If the community doesn't see any value, I can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

```
public String getOrdinal(int day) { 
    String ordinal; 
    switch (day % 20) { 
        case 1: 
            ordinal = "st"; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            ordinal = "nd"; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            ordinal = "rd"; 
            break; 
        default: 
            ordinal = day > 30 > "st" : "th"; 
    } 
    return ordinal; 
}
```

Just do the modulo with 20 and it will work for all dates.
To get today's day you can use `LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()`.
or pass any day like this

```
LocalDate.getDayOfMonth()
```

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for pointing out this bug! I am using this code in the live application I will correct it over there. I have posted correct code. Please check

Comment: Your code looks to me to be correct for 1 through 31 now. Only not the easiest to understand. Allow me to suggest you write a unit test. Also I would have wanted to add a range check and throw an exception if the `day` is less than 1 or greater than 31 since the method does not always produce the expected results for such numbers.

Comment: @OleV.V. Here I am assuming that day we are getting through LocalDate , so the day will be in the range of 1 to 31

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that updates a DateTimeFormatter pattern with the correct suffix literal if it finds the pattern `d'00'`, e.g. for day of month 1 it would be replaced with `d'st'`. Once the pattern has been updated it can then just be fed into the DateTimeFormatter to do the rest.

```
private static String[] suffixes = {"th", "st", "nd", "rd"};

private static String updatePatternWithDayOfMonthSuffix(TemporalAccessor temporal, String pattern) {
    String newPattern = pattern;
    // Check for pattern `d'00'`.
    if (pattern.matches(".*[d]'00'.*")) {
        int dayOfMonth = temporal.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int relevantDigits = dayOfMonth < 30 ? dayOfMonth % 20 : dayOfMonth % 30;
        String suffix = suffixes[relevantDigits <= 3 ? relevantDigits : 0];
        newPattern = pattern.replaceAll("[d]'00'", "d'" + suffix + "'");
    }

    return newPattern;
}
```

It does require that the original pattern is updated just prior to every formatting call, e.g.

```
public static String format(TemporalAccessor temporal, String pattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(updatePatternWithDayOfMonthSuffix(temporal, pattern));
    return formatter.format(temporal);
}
```

So this is useful if the formatting pattern is defined outside of Java code, e.g. a template, where as if you can define the pattern in Java then the answer by @OleV.V. might be more appropriate

Comment: Creative and convoluted. It certainly took me a long time to understand how it works. That’s not a sign of good code.

Comment: @OleV.V. thx for the feedback - I've restructured it a bit so it's a tiny bit less verbose. Just seen your approach and I like it! I think both approaches are valid with different trade offs. Yours doesn't require any further support at the point of formatting but does require the pattern is defined using the builder that precludes pattern definition in non Java code. My approach does require additional support at point of formatting but no dependency on the builder to create the pattern so makes it a bit more flexible where the pattern can be defined. My requirements dictated the latter

Comment: Very nice account of pros and cons. You may want to include it in the answer? Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can use like this

```
fun changeDateFormats(currentFormat: String, dateString: String): String {
        var result = ""
        try {
            val formatterOld = SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            formatterOld.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")

            var date: Date? = null

            date = formatterOld.parse(dateString)

            val dayFormate = SimpleDateFormat("d", Locale.getDefault())
            var day = dayFormate.format(date)

            val formatterNew = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a, d'" + getDayOfMonthSuffix(day.toInt()) + "' MMM yy", Locale.getDefault())

            if (date != null) {
                result = formatterNew.format(date)
            }

        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return dateString
        }

        return result
    }


    private fun getDayOfMonthSuffix(n: Int): String {
        if (n in 11..13) {
            return "th"
        }
        when (n % 10) {
            1 -> return "st"
            2 -> return "nd"
            3 -> return "rd"
            else -> return "th"
        }
    }
```

set like this

```
  txt_chat_time_me.text = changeDateFormats("SERVER_DATE", "DATE")
```

Answer (score -3):

The following method can be used to get the formatted string of the date which is passed in to it. It'll format the date to say 1st,2nd,3rd,4th .. using SimpleDateFormat in Java. eg:- 1st of September 2015

```
public String getFormattedDate(Date date){
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            //2nd of march 2015
            int day=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

            switch (day % 10) {
            case 1:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'st' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            case 2:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'nd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            case 3:  
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'rd' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
            default: 
                return new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy").format(date);
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

The following is a more efficient answer to the question rather than hard-coding the style.

To change the day to ordinal number you need to use the following [suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939329/how-to-set-format-of-current-date-time-to-different-format/17960888?noredirect=1#17960888).

```
DD +     TH = DDTH  result >>>> 4TH

OR to spell the number add SP to the format

DD + SPTH = DDSPTH   result >>> FOURTH
```

Find my completed answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939329/how-to-set-format-of-current-date-time-to-different-format/17960888?noredirect=1#17960888) question.

Comment: Question is to format in Java not in Oracle database
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm#BABGDDFB

Java use SimpleDateFormat for date:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -9):

```
public String getDaySuffix(int inDay)
{
  String s = String.valueOf(inDay);

  if (s.endsWith("1"))
  {
    return "st";
  }
  else if (s.endsWith("2"))
  {
    return "nd";
  }
  else if (s.endsWith("3"))
  {
    return "rd";
  }
  else
  {
    return "th";
  }
}
```

Comment: It should not use endsWith(); which produce wrong output