# Parsing dates of the format "January 10th, 2010" in Java? (with ordinal indicators, st|nd|rd|th)

Tags: java, date

I need to parse the dates of the format "January 10th, 2010" in Java. How can I do this?

How to handle the [ordinal indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator), the `st`, `nd`, `rd`, or `th` trailing the day number?

Comment: The problem is the "th" (and presumably "rd" and "nd"), right?

Comment: Thanx everyone...it's working by escaping the characters.

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
String s = "January 10th, 2010";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
System.out.println("" + dateFormat.parse(s.replaceAll("(?:st|nd|rd|th),", "")));
```

but you need to make sure you are using the right [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to properly parse the month name.

I know you can include general texts inside the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern. However in this case the text is dependent on the info and is actually not relevant to the parsing process.

This is actually the simplest solution I can think of. But I would love to be shown wrong.

You can avoid the pitfalls exposed in one of the comments by doing something similar to this:

```
String s = "January 10th, 2010";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
System.out.println("" + dateFormat.parse(s.replaceAll("(?<= \\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th),(?= \\d+$)", "")));
```

This will allow you to not match `Jath,uary 10 2010` for example.

Comment: i know you can include general texts inside the `SimpleDataFormat` pattern. However in this case the text is dependent on the info and is actually not relevant to the parsing process. The simplest solution i know is this. But i would love to be shown wrong.

Comment: But will accept `"January th,10 2010"`,`"Janth,uary th,10 2010"` etc also, which maybe is not a desired behavior.

Comment: @michael Well. if you want to be pedantic you can tweak the regex a little to fix that. It depends on how much trust you have in the input data.

Comment: The second version of the replaceAll expression is slightly broken. Firstly, it was missing a paren at the beginning of the expression, and also the \d chars needed an extra backslash. I fixed that above, but it still fails for me with a complaint that the length of the lookbehind is not fixed due to the wildcard. My particular case is slightly different formatting, so I've just gone for a single preceding digit instead: `dateStr.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)", "")`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. Rather than the `SimpleDateFormat` class used in the two top-voted answer today you should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It offers a couple of nice solutions.

### Easy solution

We first define a formatter for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSING_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "MMMM d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'], uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then we use it like this:

```
    String dateString = "January 10th, 2010";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, PARSING_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println("Parsed date: " + date);
```

Output is:

> Parsed date: 2010-01-10

The square brackets `[]` in the format pattern string enclose optional parts, and the single quotes enclose literal text. So `d['st']['nd']['rd']['th']` means that there may be `st`, `nd`, `rd` and/or `th` after the day of month.

### More solid solution

A couple of limitations with the approach above are

1. It accepts any ordinal indicator, for example `10st` and even `10stndrdth`.
2. While the formatter works for parsing, you cannot use it for formatting (it would give `January 10stndrdth, 2010`).

If you want better validation of the ordinal indicator or you want the possibility of formatting the date back into a string, you may build your formatter in this way:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTING_AND_PARSING_FORMATTER;
static {
    Map<Long, String> ordinalNumbers = new HashMap<>(42);
    ordinalNumbers.put(1L, "1st");
    ordinalNumbers.put(2L, "2nd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(3L, "3rd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(21L, "21st");
    ordinalNumbers.put(22L, "22nd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(23L, "23rd");
    ordinalNumbers.put(31L, "31st");
    for (long d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
        ordinalNumbers.putIfAbsent(d, "" + d + "th");
    }

    FORMATTING_AND_PARSING_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("MMMM ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ordinalNumbers)
            .appendPattern(", uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

This will parse the date string the same as the one above. Let’s also try it for formatting:

```
    System.out.println("Formatted back using the same formatter: "
            + date.format(FORMATTING_AND_PARSING_FORMATTER));
```

> Formatted back using the same formatter: January 10th, 2010

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [My answer to a question about *formatting* ordinal indicators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/5772882) from which I took the more solid formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `nd` etc as literals in a [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can define the four needed format and try them. Starting with `th` first, because I guess this will occur more often. If it fails with `ParseException`, try the next one. If all fail, throw the ParseException. The code here is just a concept. In real-life you may would not generate the formats new everytime and may think about thread-safety.

```
public static Date hoolaHoop(final String dateText) throws ParseException
        {
        ParseException pe=null;
        String[] sss={"th","nd","rd","st"};
        for (String special:sss)
        {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d'"+special+",' yyyy");
        
        try{
        return sdf.parse(dateText);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
        // remember for throwing later 
        pe=e;
        }
        }
        throw pe;
        }
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
         String[] dateText={"January 10th, 2010","January 1st, 2010","January 2nd, 2010",""};
         for (String dt:dateText) {System.out.println(hoolaHoop(dt))};
        }
```

Output:

> Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 GMT 2010
>
> Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2010
>
> Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2010
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

`"th","nd","rd","st"` is of course only suitable for Locales with english language. Keep that in mind. In france, `"re","nd"` etc I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is another easy way ,but need to include **apache commons jar**.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.*;

String s = "January 10th, 2010";
String[] freakyFormat = {"MMM dd'st,' yyyy","MMM dd'nd,' yyyy","MMM dd'th,' yyyy","MMM dd'rd,' yyyy"};
DateUtils du = new DateUtils();
System.out.println("" + du.parseDate(s,freakyFormat));
```