# java how to parse a string with spaces and other texts to java.util.date

Tags: java

java how to parse a string with with spaces and other texts to java.util.date
How do you pass "11th Jan, 2012 02:51:01 +0300" String to a java.util.date

Comment: Search and learn SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat cannot parse the day-of-month suffix i.e. the "th" in "11th Jan".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can specify your own format from which a date `String` gets parsed to a `Date` object.

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date d = sdf.parse("11nd Jan, 2012 02:51:01 +0300".replaceAll("st|nd|rd|th", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and create an appropriate format String.

For the ordinals (st/nd/rd/th) see this question: [Parsing dates of the format "January 10th, 2010" in Java? (with ordinal indicators, st|nd|rd|th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722289/parsing-dates-of-the-format-january-10th-2010-in-java)

Comment: you can't parse the day suffix i.e. the "th" in "11th Jan" using a SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score -1):

You use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your text.

[How to convert descriptive dates into Java Date format](http://www.coderanch.com/t/555695/java/java/convert-descriptive-dates-Java-Date) handles the st/nd/rd/th issue.