# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Augu 16, 1979"

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

if i try replace("st", "") so it occurs  URLjava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Augu 16, 1979"

please help ....

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("August 21st, 2012");
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Hi Chaitanya. Try to rewrite question to better fit our community standards please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a date’s ordinal indicator ( st, nd, rd, th ) in a date-time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514346/parsing-a-date-s-ordinal-indicator-st-nd-rd-th-in-a-date-time-string)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I am immodest enough to recommend my own answer to the linked original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44198044/5772882) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116982/5772882) or my answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `replace("st", "")` also removes the `st` ending of `August`, resulting in the input string seen in the error message.

To handle this, you need to make sure the `st` suffix is right after a digit, so it's part of the day value. You also need to handle all of `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, and `4th`.

This means that you should use regular expression, like this:

```
replaceFirst("(?<=\\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)", "")
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test("August 20th, 2012");
    test("August 21st, 2012");
    test("August 22nd, 2012");
    test("August 23rd, 2012");
    test("August 24th, 2012");
}
static void test(String input) throws ParseException {
    String modified = input.replaceFirst("(?<=\\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)", "");

    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse(modified);
    System.out.println(targetFormat.format(date));
}
```

*Output*

```
20120820
20120821
20120822
20120823
20120824
```

Comment: For my part I would not do any replacement in the original string before parsing it. No matter if we’re talking the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the notorious and outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, both are capable of parsing the string as it is using optional parts and literal texts as shown in some of the answers to the linked original questions.

Answer (score 0):

`MMMM` format should give full month name. Try to use `Locale.US` .

Comment: This seems to be beside the problem that the questioner is having (see the other answers for details; I admit it’s not very well explained in the question itself).

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing "st" also in "August". Use `replace("1st", "1")`.

Comment: It sounds simple, but will grow as you need to do it for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, …, 11th, 12th, … up to 31st.