# get date format from given date in android

Tags: android, date, android-date

Hello i am new in android. Can anybody help me to find how i get date format Sun 15th July from 2012-07-15? I found examples but each of it is for various different date-formats. Please help me to find this.

Comment: Take a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Comment: Whatever format you want, [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get idea from my another answer in [Convert Date time in “April 6th, 2012 ” format][1]

[1]: [Convert Date time in "April 6th, 2012 " format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316827/convert-date-time-in-april-6th-2012-format/10317196#10317196) here you can only change the April to Sun and 2012 to month.

Like:-

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
symbols.setShortWeekdays(new String[]{"Sun","Mon"....});
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE", symbols);
```

from this code you will get Days in "Sun,Mon,Tue..." Short Format

So pass this symbols in your SimpleDateFormat class.