# format date from 1990-04-07 to 07th April 1990

Tags: java, android

I have retrieved date from contact database and the value is 1990-04-07 that is `yy-MM-dd` .
How to format the date to 07th April 1990

Please suggest me ....

Comment: The "th" part is a bit tricky - SimpleDateFormat doesn't handle that. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: Please read this question and answers, it may be useful for you [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316827/convert-date-time-in-april-6th-2012-format

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Android Developer page for DateFormat: [Android Developer Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

What you're looking for is DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() in the example they provide.