# Can i Convert Date in this format "9th Nov 20" in Android?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting, ordinal-indicator

As per Project requirement, i want to convert date in this format "9th Nov 20". Please can any one suggest solution for this?

Comment: I’m immodest enugh to recommend [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/5772882).

Comment: You tagged your question simpledateformat, but you should consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
String date = format.format(new Date());
    
if(date.endsWith("1") && !date.endsWith("11"))
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d'st', yyyy");
else if(date.endsWith("2") && !date.endsWith("12"))
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d'nd', yyyy");
else if(date.endsWith("3") && !date.endsWith("13"))
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d'rd', yyyy");
else 
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d'th', yyyy");
    
String yourDate = format.format(new Date());
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317196/13564911

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I understand, I checked your answer about this topic, it seems longer than this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/13564911

Comment: Yes, @IlyasseSalama, exactly. In my answer there I try to say why I prefer the longer version. There’s also a shorter one for you to take if you prefer. Taste differs. And my recommendation to stay away from `SimpleDateFormat` is invariable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date= new Date();
SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String result = spf.format(date);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: i need th extension..is it possible?

Comment: what you mean by extension?

Comment: example- i need st for 1 as 1st,nd for 2 as 2nd and rd for 3 as 3rd