# how to change the date format to another?

Tags: java, android

From a database I am getting a date which's format is like this

2012-7-8

but I want to convert this to look something like this

2012 July 8th

but I am unable to do this, is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

You must first parse the date with A SimpleDateFormat object, converting string from database to a Date object. Then you shall format this date object with another instance of SimpleDateFormat, converting the date object to astring, formatted according to you choice.

You may check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of SimpleDateFormat for details on how to specify the format.

```
public class DateFormatTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String dateFromDatebase = "2012-7-8";

    SimpleDateFormat databaseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = databaseFormat.parse(dateFromDatebase);

    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMMM d");
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(dateFromDatebase + " -> " + formattedDate);

}}
```

This outputs `2012-7-8 -> 2012 July 8`

Comment: can you please provide me a snippet of code of the method that will work?

Comment: Well what you kind of overlooked was the requirement to meet '8th'. So I think it should also be '1st' and '2nd' etcpp. If i am right, Reyjohn might find his answer to this part of his problem right here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Simple Date Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..... Just one line of code....

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

     System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY MMM dd").format(new Date()));
      }
  }
```