# How to parse a Java Date to customized string format like "17^th of Jan 2014" ('th' is a superscript)

Tags: java

I want to parse a java Date object to the format like below

[image]

I tied the below codes

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");       
    DateFormat dfz = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String d = dfz.format(date);
    System.out.println(d);
```

then the out put will  be like

[image]

I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351013/how-to-format-date-to-string-like-31st-dec-2000-in-java) and using that I could get the below format

[image]

Is there any built-in functionality in java to parse a date object to the first where the `th` is a `superscript` format or do I need to do it manually ? And how to do it manually ?
What is the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: How are you displaying the results? Is it in a console, swing component, website...?

Comment: I checked, and unicode doesn't include superscript t or h

Comment: So, do you want to parse, or do you want to format?

Comment: I want to display the result in a div tag. In front end of a web site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the UI you are using you need to handle super script separately.
for HTML simply use tag **17<sup>th</sup>** (`17<sup>th</sup>`)

Comment: So if I return '17 Jan 2014' to front end then I have to manually do this. ? Like by tokenizing the date and add the sup tag.