# Change a String date into another String date

Tags: java, string, date

I've got a `String` like this: `2013-04-19`, and I want to change it into : `April 19th 2013`. I know there is some classes in Java like `SimpleDateFormat`, but I don't know what kind of function I should use. Maybe I need to choose the class `Pattern`? I need some help.

Comment: You can start reading about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: A quick look at any example for SimpleDateFormat will shoudl taht you need to `parse` and then `format` the String to a date and back to a String

Comment: Also, you will have to write a custom way to say `19th` as it's not standard in `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Also; as always when dealing with dates - consider using (JodaTime)[http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, which should give you correct "th", "st", "rd" and "nd" for days.

```
public static String getDayOfMonthSuffix(final int n) {
        if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
            return "th";
        }
        switch (n % 10) {
            case 1:  return "st";
            case 2:  return "nd";
            case 3:  return "rd";
            default: return "th";
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-04-19");

        int day = Integer.parseInt(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(d));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd'" + getDayOfMonthSuffix(day) + "' yyyy");
        String s = sdf.format(d);

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Which will print `April 19th 2013`

(Day termination adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011232/1332690))

Comment: Thank you i will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: It will also display "13rd" and "12nd"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String originalDate = "2013-04-19";
Date date = null;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(originalDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy").format(date);
```

Will not print the st, nd, rd, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just using parse method from SimpleDateFormat class
try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd YYYY").parse("2013-04-19");
```