# Converting date to string in vb script

Tags: vbscript

I have date like **6/24/2013** , i want to get only month name and date like **June 24th** as output in vb script.

Comment: I tried using cstr(date()) but its returning 6/24/2013

Comment: Is this question about VBScript or VB.net? They're different languages. Also, do you have that date as a string, or as a date value?

Comment: I tried using this code MonthName(Month(Now())) and date am hard coding ,so i got jun 24th

Comment: Would you awfully mind answering the questions you're being asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two functions to deal with the two (sub) problems - name of month, ordinal of number - separately:

```
Option Explicit

Dim n
For n = -2 To 10
    WScript.Echo fmtDate(DateAdd("d", n, Date))
Next

Function fmtDate(dtX)
  fmtDate = MonthName(Month(dtX)) & " " & ordinal(Day(dtX))
End Function

' !! http://stackoverflow.com/a/4011232/603855
Function ordinal(n)
  Select Case n Mod 10
    case 1    : ordinal = "st"
    case 2    : ordinal = "nd"
    case 3    : ordinal = "rd"
    case Else : ordinal = "th"
  End Select
  ordinal = n & ordinal
End Function
```

output:

```
June 22nd
June 23rd
June 24th
June 25th
June 26th
June 27th
June 28th
June 29th
June 30th
July 1st
July 2nd
July 3rd
July 4th
```

**Update:**

(Hopefully) improved version of ordinal():

```
Function ordinal(n)
  Select Case n Mod 31
    case  1, 21, 31 : ordinal = "st"
    case  2, 22     : ordinal = "nd"
    case  3, 23     : ordinal = "rd"
    case Else       : ordinal = "th"
  End Select
  ordinal = n & ordinal
End Function
```