# Date format in Java (or Android)

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have date in **dd/mm/yyyy** format but i want to parse it in something like **2nd May or 5th June**
I'm able to parse it to 2 May or 5 June but I need to append that nd or th with date too
Can anyone please suggest something using `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat` class?

Edit:
A little snapshot of what I've already tried:-

```
Date d = Date.parse("20/6/2013");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
String dateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: So far.. `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");` and also tried looking up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: can you please provide li'l bit of code?

Comment: Have an `HashMap`  which contain `Date` as `key` and date suffix for example st , nd  as `value` . And get the proper suffix of the `Date` as `Key` from `HahMap` . You can have only 10 entries in the `Hashmap'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use some method like this :-

```
String getDaySuffix(final int n) {
    if(n < 1 || n > 31)
        return "Invalid date";
    if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) 
        return "th";

    switch (n % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate ur way but I need something if it's already in the API. Should be able to change the format.

Comment: Why won't you go about it this way?

Comment: ok.. ur code almost worked for me.. u might want to remove those = signs from `if(n <= 1 || n >= 31)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to split it with the " ". like below:

```
Staring split[] = dateString .split[" "];
String date = split[0];
String suffix = getDate(Integer.parseInt(date));
String YourDesireString = date + suffix + " " + split[1];
```

The function of getDate is as below

```
String getDate(final int n) {
    if(n <= 1 || n >= 31)
        return "Invalid date";
    if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (n % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
   }
}
```

YourDesireString is the answer what you want is. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done by SimpleDateFormat. But here is the alternate solution to achieve the same.

```
static String[] suffixes =
  //    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
       "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
       "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
  //    30    31
       "th", "st" };

  Date date = new Date();
 int day = Calendar.getInstance().setTime(date).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 String dayStr = day + suffixes[day];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function to get the date format like 1st or 5th .. we have to manually add the suffix to a date..Hope the below code might be usefull for you.

public class WorkWithDate {

```
private static String getCurrentDateInSpecificFormat(Calendar currentCalDate) {
    String dayNumberSuffix = getDayNumberSuffix(currentCalDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" d'" + dayNumberSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(currentCalDate.getTime());
}

private static String getDayNumberSuffix(int day) {
    if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (day % 10) {
        case 1:
            return "st";
        case 2:
            return "nd";
        case 3:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(getCurrentDateInSpecificFormat(Calendar.getInstance()));
}
```

}