# How to set format of current date time to different format?

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime-format

I use the following code to retrieve the current date and time, then add it to table using following method.

```
 Change 2013-07-29 23:20:34.0 to 29th July 2013, 11:20 PM
```

DateTime

```
 public Date getCurrentDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("current:" + dateFormat.format(date));
        return date;
    }
```

Hibernate

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCurrentDateTime() {
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: For the required date format you can use dd-MMMM-yyyy how ever it will not show the th

Comment: so you want to format it once you get it from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the day to ordinal number you need to use the following [suffix](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm). have a look at this [link](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_date_format.jsp) as well

```
DD +     TH = DDTH  result >>>> 4TH

OR to spell the number add SP to the format

DD + SPTH = DDSPTH   result >>> FOURTH
```

Also use the fmt library to format the date on jsp pages

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

 <fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="short" 
      value="${date}"/>
```

Comment: This is the answer I am searching for and thanks for [this link](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_date_format.jsp)

Answer (score 4):

A `Date` object doesn't *have* a format. (Neither `java.sql.Date` nor `java.util.Date`.) The database will just store it in the table in whatever native representation it chooses (almost certainly not text) and when you retrieve the data it's up to *you* to format it how you wish.

To change the format used by `System.out.println`, just change the pattern you're passing to the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) constructor - see the documentation for details. Note that you should consider which time zone and `Locale` you're interested in, too - for example, month names won't be the same between different locales, and different locales also have different expected formats. (Even within the same language, there are different conventions.)

You'll find the "th" of "29th" hard to handle with `SimpleDateFormat` - I don't believe it supports ordinals. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java) may help you though. (It's going to be ugly code, mind you - I would suggest changing the format to remove the ordinal if you possibly can.)

Comment: The question is that then how to format it once it is retrieved from database.

Comment: @TimNorman: Use `SimpleDateFormat`, as you're doing - just adjust the pattern to whatever you want. I've added a documentation link to my answer.

Comment: you can add th to make it ordinal have a look at my answer.

Comment: @J888: That's formatting it on the *database* side though - which I think is rarely a good idea, personally.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this ??

for hibernate

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateBufferString = format.format(date);
Date dateBuffer;
try {

dateBuffer = format.parse(dateBufferString);
System.out.println("Database Date Format :" + date);
System.out.println("(dd-MM-yyyy) date: " + format.format(date));
System.out.println("dateBufferSTring " + dateBufferString);
System.out.println("dateBuffer: " + dateBuffer);
```

Comment: I have provided an example of the expected output I have tried this before neither helped.