# Date formatting in Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I format a `LocalDate` instance to the tune of `18th Aug, 2013` using Joda Time Date formatter?

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate();
string = localDate.toString(dateformat); //what to put in here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you will get is

```
String dateString = localDate.toString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

i.e. the date affix ("th" in this case) is not supported

Comment: No way to get st, nd, rd or th?

Comment: That's not provided by the library unfortunately

Comment: Any other library recommended?

Comment: `JodaTime` is fine (the best even :)). If you really want you could do as shown in the answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)

Comment: there is a way, use https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html

Comment: that won't work - the `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` won't be handled using `DateTimeFormatter`. Thanks for the downvote BTW ;P

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddd MMMM, yyyy");
string = localDate.toString();
```

More information about Joda Time formatting you can find at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html. there's also explained how to use Builder to make custom date patterns.

Good luck