# Convert string date to simple date format

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am scraping a webpage that contains dates in this format: "8th November 2013". After I have returned the dates they are organized into an unordered array of strings. What I want to do then is somehow convert these strings to a simple date format like yyyy-MM-dd so I can order them and use them for interacting with the calendar?

Comment: Does this thread get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: Yeah if I did it this way I would have to write an entire class to parse and format the string dates to my liking!? Very time consuming but seems it may be my only choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private String dateLongStringConvert(String dateLongString) {

    // split long date string into string array
    String[] dateArray = dateLongString.split(" ");

    // get day of month as an integer (strip out non numeric chars)
    int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateArray[0].replaceAll("\\D+", ""));

    // Convert month string to number
    String month = "";
    switch (dateArray[1]) {
        case "January":
            month = "01";
        case "Feburary":
            month = "02";            
        case "March":
            month = "03";            
        case "April":
            month = "04";            
        case "May":
            month = "05";            
        case "June":
            month = "06";            
        case "July":
            month = "07";            
         case "August":
            month = "08";           
          case "September":
            month = "09";          
        case "October":
            month = "10";            
        case "Novemember":
            month = "11";
        case "December":
            month = "12";                
    }
    // return formated date string
    return dateArray[2] + "-" + month + "-" + String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth);
}
```

Comment: This worked but I had to make a couple of changes. I had to remove the switch(String) because switch statement on String objects is a new feature introduced in Java 1.7. Unfortunately Android requires version 1.6 or 1.5. Instead I used multiple if else statements. Also when split the string into an array had to split("\\s+") to identify the white spaces. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
String inputDate = "8th November 2013";
inputDate = inputDate.replaceAll("([0-9])st|nd|rd|th|\\.", "$1"); // get rid of the th.
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM y", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(inputDate); // parse input date
String outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date); // format to output date
```

Comment: Tried this and it removes the th fine but when it tries to format the result I get the following exception: "Unparseable date: "8 November 2013"

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do such thing is to use a parser like Stanford Temporal Tagger and figure out dates from the text. A nice GUI(http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) is provided by the team to evaluate the tool

Answer (score 0):

to_char( 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:ss')