# How to convert date String in java such that the date ends with a suuffix st, nd, rd, th etc.?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm getting a date String in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" and I have to print it in a format such that if the date is February 11, 2014 then it should print Feb, 11th 2014. How to do that using SimpleDateFormat Time and Date pattern?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: @helderdarocha you can flag the question as duplicate

Comment: You cannot do that using `SimpleDateFormat` patterns. refer to the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html