# java calendar display name style for day of month with ordinal indicator

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, days

Can Java be used to get different styles of day_of_month?

i.e. "21st" and "22nd" rather than just "21" and "22"?

also what are the 'st' and 'nd' at the end of dates called for future reference?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in stock JDK APIs to do this.  If you google around you'll find several folks who have implemented one-offs like http://r3dux.org/2011/10/how-to-get-human-friendly-dates-in-java-using-the-calendar-class/

Comment: The "st" and "nd" at the end are called [ordinal indicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDK (including Java 8) does not offer a solution out of the box, and other libraries like JodaTime also not. But you can look at this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java) to get some ideas.

Furthermore, I think you can reasonably try your solution for ordinal day numbers only for English, but what about other languages? That is an important reason why no library can give support. In JodaTime or JSR-310 there might be an English-only handwritten solution possible on the base of introducing a specialized field, for example in JSR-310 the interface `java.time.temporal.TemporalField`, but this is surely a lot of work.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to do it the hard way, id rather not have any more API's than what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

No you may need to write a small utility function which will help you achieving the same in Java

you ca refer SO Answer here for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011232/2381006)