# How Set Max & Min Date In WHEEL DatePicker In Android

Tags: android, datepicker

In my application am trying [DatePicker](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-date-picker-example.html) to set date.I want to set date picker Maximum date is as today date according to system date.i don't know how to set date picker maximum date as today date.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out

Here is my code :

```
    public class UserDob extends Activity {

    TextView tvDisplayDate;
     DatePicker datePickerBirthday;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_dob);

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));     
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        datePickerBirthday=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
        tvDisplayDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewUserDate);

         int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
                datePickerBirthday.setCalendarViewShown(false);
            }

            SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            String dateStr = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            String[] dateSplit = dateStr.split("-");
            int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
            int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
            int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);

            // to show date and day of week in the TextView
            setHumanReadableDate(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);

            // initialize date picker listener
            // currentMonth - 1, because on the picker, 0 is January
            datePickerBirthday.init(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, currentDay, birthdayListener);


    }
     // the date picker listener
   OnDateChangedListener birthdayListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDateChanged(DatePicker birthDayDatePicker,
               int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay) {

           try{

               // currentMonth + 1, to retrieve proper month
               setHumanReadableDate(newYear, newMonth + 1, newDay);

           } catch (NullPointerException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   };

   // show the user a better date format
   public void setHumanReadableDate(int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay){
       try {

           String clickedDate = newYear + "-" + newMonth + "-" + newDay;
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
           Date d = null;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse(clickedDate);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'is' EEEE", Locale.US);
           String dateStr = sdfDateTime.format(d);

           tvDisplayDate.setText(dateStr);

       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above API 11 
For min date you can use

```
android:minDate="mm/dd/yyyy"
or setMinDate(long time)
```

For Max date

```
android:maxDate="mm/dd/yyyy" // In XML
setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());// Current time
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Answer (score 0):

if you are using API level above 11 then use `setMaxDate`  of `DatePicker` to set mex date. otherwise create a custom DatePicker and override `onDateSet` method, and apply your validation here like below

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDateSet :which:");
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    cl.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    if(cl.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
        this.mListener.onDateSet(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select any date before this.",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

}
```