# How do you format the day of the month to say “11th”, “21st” or “23rd” in Dart?

Tags: date, internationalization, dart

I have a date and want to display the date with the suffix th, st, rd, etc.

Here is my dart code.

```dart
int year = date.year;
int month = date.month;
int day = date.day;

DateTime dateSelected = new DateTime(year, month, day);
var formatter = new DateFormat('EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy');
displayDate = formatter.format(dateSelected);
```

This displays dates as "Wednesday April 23, 2014" for example, but I need "Wednesday April 23rd, 2014".

I'm using the intl package.

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Comment: Maybe it is part of the intlx package, but I don't know

Comment: If this is only going to need to appear in English speaking countries, I recommend something similar to this answer for Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: Remember it's not always necessary to write it like that ```One writes January 1, but says “January first.”
One writes November 12, but says “November twelfth.”

The only time to use the “th, nd, rd” and “st” with numbers is with ordinal numbers.``` https://www.dailywritingtips.com/january-1-doesnt-need-an-st/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy), inspired by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

Just simply add the `do` date pattern. See below

```
Jiffy.parseFromList([2014, 4, 23]).format("EEEE MMMM do, yyyy"); // Wednesday April 23rd, 2014
```

You can also add your DateTime object

```
Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime(2014, 4, 23)).format("EEEE MMMM do, yyyy"); // Wednesday April 23rd, 2014
```

Comment: You seem to have changed the format to require a named parameter??   '''Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime(2014, 4, 23)).format(pattern: "EEEE MMMM do, yyyy");'''

Answer (score 20):

```
String getDayOfMonthSuffix(int dayNum) {
    if(!(dayNum >= 1 && dayNum <= 31)) {
      throw Exception('Invalid day of month');
    }

    if(dayNum >= 11 && dayNum <= 13) {
      return 'th';
    }

    switch(dayNum % 10) {
      case 1: return 'st';
      case 2: return 'nd';
      case 3: return 'rd';
      default: return 'th';
    }
}
```

The above method gets the suffix for you. You can use string concatenation or string interpolation to put together the format you want. e.g

```dart
'$day ${getDayOfMonthSuffix(day)}'
```

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think that there’s build-in functionality for that. You could format the date like that:

```
format(DateTime date) {
  var suffix = "th";
  var digit = date.day % 10; 
  if ((digit > 0 && digit < 4) && (date.day < 11 || date.day > 13)) {  
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][digit - 1];
  }
  return new DateFormat("EEEE MMMM d'$suffix', yyyy").format(date);
}
```

Note: If you don’t want explicit the '01st' one `d` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

May not be better...but shorter

```
static final _dayMap = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'};
static String dayOfMonth(int day) => "$day${_dayMap[day] ?? 'th'}";
```

Comment: simple, intuitive and fast --> love it!

Comment: What about `dayOfMonth(21)`. Your function currently returns `21th`.
Try this instead: `static String dayOfMonth(int day) => "$day${_dayMap[day % 10] ?? 'th'}";`

Comment: @AnshSaini Unfortunately yours would fail too for cases like dayOfMonth(12) and others. It would return 12nd.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank your for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

**A SIMPLER/CLEANER SOLUTION:**

Install the package [moment_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/moment_dart#formatting) from your terminal.

```
flutter pub add moment_dart
```

**Usage:**

```
import 'package:moment_dart/moment_dart.dart';
.
.
.
final now = Moment.now();
print(now.format('dddd, Do'));
```

**Output on your console:**

```
flutter: Wednesday, 23rd
```

So to achieve **exactly** what you want, it would have to be:

```
print(now.format('dddd MMMM Do, YYYY'));
```

**Output on your console:**

```
flutter: Wednesday April 23rd, 2014
```