# Output readable day-of-month with joda-time

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to get a `jodatime` `DateTime` object to output in the format that I want. At the moment, my format string is:

```
dt.toString("EEEE dd\nMMMM YYYY");
```

This outputs as:

```
Wednesday 04
June 2014
```

However I'd like to display the `DAY` with the suffix, for example:

`1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, `4th`

Is there a built-in way of doing this with jodatime, or do I have to write my own function for this?

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java?lq=1

Comment: its not _exactly_ a duplicate... you are asking specifically jodatime, looks like that one is more generically java. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String formatFirst = "EEEE dd'st'\nMMMM YYYY";
String formatSecond = "EEEE dd'nd'\nMMMM YYYY";
String formatThird = "EEEE dd'rd'\nMMMM YYYY";
String formatStd = "EEEE dd'th'\nMMMM YYYY";

String pattern;

switch (dt.getDayOfMonth()) {
  case 1:
  case 21:
  case 31:
    pattern = formatFirst;
    break;
  case 2:
  case 22:
    pattern = formatSecond;
    break;
  case 3:
  case 23:
    pattern = formatThird;
    break;
  default:
    pattern = formatStd;
}

String output = dt.toString(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the docs on the JodaTime website (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html), it doesn't look like there is a built in function to do this format.

Can see a similar question here as well for an example of how to manually do the formatting -- [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java? (ordinal indicator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar Kotlin version of this answer. This just outputs Months including their Ordinal.

```
fun getDayOfMonthDayWithOrdinal(date: DateTime): String {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd")
        val monthDay = formatter.print(date).toInt()
        return when (monthDay) {
            1, 21, 31 -> "${monthDay}st"
            2, 22 -> "${monthDay}nd"
            3, 23 -> "${monthDay}rd"
            else -> "${monthDay}th"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll jave to implement your own [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) for that.