# How to convert a date having ordinal format 1st March 1994?

Tags: java, date-format

I want format a date given in the following format 1st March 1990. The date should be formatted to YYYY-MM-DD. I have the following code. It gives me an unparsable date. From this i can understand, this is not the correct way to format this date as its not a valid pattern.

```
public class DateFormattingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateString = "1st March 1984";

        dateString = dateString.replaceFirst("[a-zA-Z]{2}","") ;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
        Date rightNow = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(rightNow);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

I have revised and looked for date formatting patterns as well. I cannot find something related to this pattern "1st March 1990". I don't want sample code for this issue. I want to find out what am i doing wrong in here? Can someone suggest an approach to parse such a date?

Thanks.

Comment: Guys, i have added the code and updated my question subject also, if anyone stucks at the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems.

- First, you're trying to *parse* the date using the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. That's not the format of your data, which is why parsing is failing.
- Second, you're expecting a `Date` object to retain information about a particular format. It doesn't. Instead, you would parse from one text format to a `Date`, and then use another `DateFormat` (with the desired output format) to format the `Date` into a `String`. `Date.toString()` will always use the same format, regardless of how you arrived at the `Date`.
- Third, your format of `YYYY-MM-DD` isn't really what you want - you want `yyyy-MM-dd`. `YYYY` is the "weekyear", and `DD` is the "day of year".

I don't know of any `SimpleDateFormat` approach which would handle the ordinal part of your input string ("1st", "2nd" etc) - you'll probably need to put a bit of work into stripping that out. Once you've got a value such as "1 March 1990" you can parse with a `SimpleDateFormat` using the pattern `d MMMM yyyy`. Make sure you set the time zone and the locale appropriately.

Comment: Since the pattern is characterized by the ordinal markers being the first letters in the string, I think they can be easily removed with `dateString.replaceFirst( "[a-zA-Z]{2}", "" )`

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Yes, if the value is assumed to be correct to start with, that should work.]

Comment: @RealSkeptic, i am almost there, lemme check with this regular expression replacement. This site is just awesome.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean in point-2 when we say Date.toString() will always use the same format? Which format?

Comment: @benz: The one specified in the [Javadoc for `Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--). When in doubt, check the docs :)

Comment: Thanks a ton Jon. :) Sorry i will next time first reference the javadoc. Thanks a ton again.

Answer (score 2):

Your date `1st` was not incorporated into the Java DateFormat. If you can switch to `1` and use the appropriate `DateFormat`, the parsing of Date will work or else you would need to convert the `ordinal number` to `number` by stripping the `suffix`.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java) might be a good related post to peek at.

Comment: Piyush, what do you exactly mean by converting to Ordinal number? There is not format in java, taking care of ordinal numbers.

Comment: @benz: I mean the other way around, converting the ordinal number to number. Have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `dateString` does not match the pattern specified in your `simpleDateFormat` format. It is expecting a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, the meaning of these symbols can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).