# How to convert date time from one format to another in Android?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

I want to convert date and time from "2014-11-25 14:30" format to " Nov 25th,2014 at 2:30pm ". Could anybody please tell how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to search at least on Google or on Stackoverflow for existing threads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
String date = "2014-11-25 14:30";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Comment: @Nidhi you most welcome....let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Yeah.I want to show date as 25th ,but this gives the value as 25T

Comment: @Nidhi its okay, just give me a minute.

Comment: @Nidhi I think its not providing by SimpleDateFormat class. You have to manually put it.

Comment: @Nidhi Ya you have to do it manually, just visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: yeah i am already using the above link and some others to have a solution. Just wanted to know if there is any easier way to do this thing. But thanks a lot for your reply. :)

Comment: @Nidhi is ok, you welcome, happy coding!!! you are new comer in android?

Comment: Not a new comer. But i have not used this feature yet.

Comment: @Nidhi okay, no problem, ok take your time and start coding :)