# Removing (or allowing) ordinal characters from dynamic text with Date.parse();

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am building a self-depreciating list of dates and am using `Date.parse()` to convert rich text into a timestamp. Right now, we have a system where the user enters the date themselves, and I use a token on the backend to pull it through to that specific page.

I am trying to 'protect the user' from entering a wrong date format.

Currently, if they enter `January 12th, 2016` it won't be able to parse and create a timestamp due to `th`. However, if they enter `January 12, 2016` it can create a timestamp.

Is there a way to replace these ordinal numbers on a dynamic string? I've tried a simple jquery find/replace, but have had no luck with getting it to remove the ordinal date texts.

**What I've tried:**

```
$('.my-button').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var text = $(this).text().replace('st, ', '');
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Any ideas on a solution, or a way to make `Date.parse():` accept these extra characters?

Comment: How are free form dates getting into the system? Is it through a web page or outside of your control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a date’s ordinal indicator ( st, nd, rd, th ) in a date-time string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514346/parsing-a-date-s-ordinal-indicator-st-nd-rd-th-in-a-date-time-string)

Comment: **Do not** use Date.parse at all, it's largely implementation dependent and inconsistent. Parsing strings with the Date constructor is equivalent. The only reliable way to parse date strings is to use a parser, either one you've written or a library (moment.js is good but there are others less bulky). And when using a parser, you **must** specify the format, otherwise you leave correct parsing to chance. I don't understand the use of "self-depreciating" in this context.

Comment: @Traktor53—that answer is for Java, not javascript (which does not have a decent parser built–in).

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case of removing an ordinal from a date string like "January 12th, 2016", you can use a regular expression like:

```js
var re = /(\d{1,2})[a-z]{2}\b/i;

['January 12th, 2016','January 1st, 2016','January 2nd, 2016','20th February, 2015'].forEach(
  function(s) {
    document.write('<br>' + s.replace(re,'$1'));
  }
);
```

However, parsing strings with Date.parse (and the Date constructor, they are equivalent for parsing) is strongly recommended against. Use a parser and define the format, do not leave it to chance.

There are libraries like moment.js, however it may be too big for your requirements. There are other dedicated parsers ([*check on GitHub*](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=github%20javascript%20date%20parser)), or if you only need to support one format, write one yourself. It only requires three or four of lines of code.

Comment: This would work except the user enters the text on their side, I don't see it. So I have to be able to pull the text from the element they are writing in.