# How to convert the date value "26th May 2017" to "26/05/2017"?

Tags: java, date, java-8, date-format

Is there any java library available to parse language specific ordinal indicator/suffix?

I have a date value like the following: `26th May 2017`. I want to convert this to `26/05/2017`. Could anyone please guide me how to do?

Comment: In Java or Javascript? What do Spring and Hibernate have to do this? What research have you done on the *many* questions about date format conversion?

Comment: I want to convert 26th May 2017 to 26/05/2017 in Java program.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this in java?

Comment: Fyi, ["ordinal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)) is the technical term to use is searching on this topic of `st`, `th`, `rd`, and `nd`.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse this format directly to a Java 8 `LocalDate` using a custom date format:

```
static final Map<Long, String> ORDINAL_DAYS = new HashMap<>();
static
 {
   ORDINAL_DAYS.put(1, "1st");
   .... more ....
   ORDINAL_DAYS.put(26, "26th");
   .... more ....
   ORDINAL_DAYS.put(31, "31st");
 }

static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ORDINAL_DAYS)
  .appendLiteral(' ')
  .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
  .appendLiteral(' ')
  .appendText(ChronoField.YEAR)
  .toFormatter();


 String dateInString = "26th May 2017";

 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateInString, FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR);
```

This is using the version of `DateTimeFormatter.appendText` which accepts a map that is used to map the day string.

You will need to fill in all the missing entries in `ORDINAL_DAYS` that I have left out for brevity.

Comment: More lenient, but also briefer: `static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);`. PS Consider specifying the locale.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don’t need very strict input validation, since you are converting *from* the format with `th` on the number (or `st` or `nd` in `31st`, `2nd` and more), I suggest you simply remove those two letters first. A regex may do that:

```
    // remove st, nd, rd or th after day of month
    dateInString 
            = dateInString.replaceFirst("^(\\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)( \\w+ \\d+)$", "$1$3");
    String dateOutString = LocalDate.parse(dateInString, 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"));
```

The result is

```
26/05/2017
```

This works if your input contains a three letter abbreviation for the month, like Apr, May or Jun. To accept a full month name instead (April, May, June), you need 4 Ms instead of 3 in the format pattern: `d MMMM uuuu`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @OleV.V. in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185762/how-to-convert-the-date-value-26th-may-2017-to-26-05-2017/44190471?noredirect=1#comment75391891_44186952), you can use a pattern with optional sections (to parse the different suffixes **st**, **nd**, **rd** and **th**).

You must also use a `java.util.Locale` to force month names to English. The code will be like this:

```
String input = "26th May 2017";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter
    // parse the day followed by st, nd, rd or th (using optional patterns delimited by [])
    .ofPattern("dd['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMM yyyy")
    // force English locale to parse month names
    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
// formatter for dd/MM/yyyy output
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse(input))); // 26/05/2017
```

---

The code above will work for month names with 3 letters (like **May** or **Aug**). If you want to parse the full names (like **August** or **March**), just change `MMM` to `MMMM`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter
    // using MMMM to parse full month name (like "August")
    .ofPattern("dd['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM yyyy")
    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

---

**PS:** If you want to parse both cases (3-letter or full month names) using the same `parser`, you can do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter
    // can parse "March" or "Mar" (MMMM or MMM)
    .ofPattern("dd['st']['nd']['rd']['th'][ MMMM][ MMM] yyyy")
    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: It's a good answer, and I am happy if I have contributed to it or inspired it one way or the other. If so, a mention would be nice. In any case your explanations are probably better than mine, or at least different and thus a good supplement.

Comment: In both code snippets you may use the two-arg `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` for a bit terser code.

Comment: @OleV.V. To be honest, I saw your comment with this solution just **after** I posted my answer (I just had a very similar code here, with optional patterns and so on, and as soon as I read the question, posted the answer without looking at anything else). Sorry if I gave the impression that I copied your idea without giving any credit. Anyway, I'm gonna edit the answer to add this info. And I always forget about the 2-arg version of `ofPattern` - I usually don't need to set different locales. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you. :-)

Comment: BTW I recommend making it a rule to use the two-arg `ofPattern()`. Even when you pass `Locale.getDefault()` as the second argument, you are telling the reader (and yourself!) that you have thought about the locale and made a conscious decision about which locale to use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about Java, this link: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/ May help you.

The overall gist is:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDateExample3 {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {



        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String dateInString = "26th May 2017"; // Remove your 'th', 'nd', etc. from the input string.

        String withoutEnding = dateInString;
        //Something like this
        if(dateInString.contains("th") withoutEnding = dateInString.replace("th", "");
        if(dateInString.contains("nd") withoutEnding = dateInString.replace("nd", "");
        if(dateInString.contains("st") withoutEnding = dateInString.replace("st", "");
        if(dateInString.contains("rd") withoutEnding = dateInString.replace("rd", "");

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(withoutEnding);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Where `dd/MM/yyyy` is a date formatter that would give you
`26/05/2017`.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for a full list of the different pattern letters for `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: i want to parse date value with 'th','nd' to standard Java Date format.

Comment: @Arvinda Sorry, misread it! I just updated the answer to better answer your actual question. May not be the most efficient way (I'm at work so don't have a ton of time) but should work!

Comment: @Arvinda you may even be able to leave the suffix in, but I'm not sure, I haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks! @Chris Gilardi, Is there any java library available to parse above date format.

Comment: @Arvinda not sure.

Comment: You replacement will turn `August` into `Augu`. Unless of course it was already just `Aug` from the start, this wasn’t very clear from the question.