# Parsing the date "April 10th 2018, 07:32:45.987" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jodatime

Heyo, I'm trying to create an index pattern using Kibana, and for that I need to parse the date "April 10th 2018, 07:32:45.987" in Elasticsearch. My problem is the "th" after the 10. Elasticsearch documentation points me to the joda-time documentation: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html , but that does not tell me how it can ignore or parse those two characters. So far I have :

```
PUT mynewindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype" : {
      "properties": {
        "syslog-timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "MMM dd?? yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should replace my question marks?

In Java it would look like this:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JodaTimeTest {


    public JodaTimeTest() {
        String timeString = "April 10th 2018, 07:32:45.987";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd'th' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS||MMM dd'nd' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS||MMM dd'rd' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(timeString);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JodaTimeTest();
    }
}
```

I've tried the given solution, but that results in an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "April 10th 2018, 07:32:45.987" is too short
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
    at JodaTimeTest.<init>(JodaTimeTest.java:11)
    at JodaTimeTest.main(JodaTimeTest.java:15)
```

Extra information:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
        "range" : {
            "date" : {
                "gt" :  "now"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

returns nothing, and

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
        "range" : {
            "date" : {
                "lt" :  "now"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a date’s ordinal indicator ( st, nd, rd, th ) in a date-time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514346/parsing-a-date-s-ordinal-indicator-st-nd-rd-th-in-a-date-time-string)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this and also account for dates with `nd` and `rd`:

```
PUT mynewindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype" : {
      "properties": {
        "syslog-timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "MMM dd'th' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS||MMM dd'nd' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS||MMM dd'rd' yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. Using this I can't filter by time in Kibana. If I try to parse my time in Java with JodaTime using your filter, I get an exception. I don't think it supports the || operator. See my edit to the original post.

Comment: Of course you can filter, but you need to use the same format at query time. Can you show your query as well?

Comment: I've set Kibana to use the syslog-timestamp as a filter for the time. However, if I open the Discover interface, I get no results, even when I go 5 years back. https://i.imgur.com/7OxRo0P.png If I set it to @timestamp (which I don't want) it works fine. If I go to the console and use a search, I can see the data just fine. https://i.imgur.com/cCOBE15.png

Answer (score 0):

Val's answer doesn't work, since the || operator is not supported. For this limited test I wrote a script to remove the st, nd and rd from the logfiles. If the test is successful, haproxy will be changed to output the date without st, nd and rd.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `||` doesn't work. This is something that works in ES when you need to specify multiple date formats to be supported. It has nothing to do with Joda or Java.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere else. I'm going to delete this question since it doesn't help anyone.