# Specific DateFormat in java

Tags: java

I have a date of the form "20th Oct 2017" how do I convert it to "2017-10-20". In specific I don't see the format for `20th`. I am able to get the format for month and year `"MMM yyyy"` I would like to know the format for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] uuuu h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, parseFormatter);
```

Considering Java 8 features, you can format your date in various ways.
Just check the following formats and ways of parsing and formatting the date:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: I have already seen it and cant find how to represent `20th` can you please point it ?

Comment: try the edited code ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514346/parsing-a-date-s-ordinal-indicator-st-nd-rd-th-in-a-date-time-string says we do not have a format of that type.