# date format- february 12th,2014 in jsp

Tags: jsp

how to print date format, "February 15th,2015"..
by using this

```
 <c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.u til.Date()%>"/>
 <fmt:format Date type="date" date Style="long" value="${now}"/>
```

i got February 15,2015

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly using jstl `<fmt:format >` as such patterns are not possible .

work around is to do that in the `Java` and set it to the `request` or `session`. And unfortunately even `Java` dont have any util methods to do that . you can see it here [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java? (ordinal indicator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)