# Convert date with ordinal numbers (11th, 22nd, etc.)

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

How to convert a date having the following format

> September 22nd 2015, 10:39:42 am

to

> 09/22/2015 10:39:42

in Java 8?

My current code:

```
String value = "September 22nd 2015, 10:39:42 am";
String format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format); 
try { 
  Date date = sdf.parse(value); 
  System.out.println(date); 
  System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); 
}
catch (ParseException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Java SE 8?

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: @Puce, Yes I am using Java SE 8

Answer (score 9):

The tricky part of the format is to handle ordinal numbers (like `22nd`), i.e. handle the right suffix. There is not built-in pattern. For this, we have to build our own `DateTimeFormatter` with the help of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

[`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) has a method [`appendText(field, textLookup)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendText-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-java.util.Map-) whose goal is to look for the read text in the given map and replace it by the key associated to this value. This means we need to build a Map of all possibles days (1 to 31) with their corresponding suffix.

I took the conversion code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011232/1743880).

We also need to make sure to parse the AM/PM identifier ignoring the case (by default, it looks for AM and PM in uppercase but yours are in lowercase). This is done by calling [`parseCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--) before appending the pattern for this.

```
private static final Map<Long, String> DAYS_LOOKUP =
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 31).boxed().collect(toMap(Long::valueOf, i -> getOrdinal(i)));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("MMMM")
                                .appendLiteral(" ")
                                .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, DAYS_LOOKUP)
                                .appendLiteral(" ")
                                .appendPattern("yyyy")
                                .appendLiteral(", ")
                                .appendPattern("hh")
                                .appendLiteral(":")
                                .appendPattern("mm")
                                .appendLiteral(":")
                                .appendPattern("ss")
                                .appendLiteral(" ")
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern("a")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = formatter.parse("September 22nd 2015, 10:39:42 am", LocalDateTime::from);
    String text = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(dateTime);
    System.out.println(text);
}

private static String getOrdinal(int n) {
    if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
        return n + "th";
    }
    switch (n % 10) {
        case 1:  return n + "st";
        case 2:  return n + "nd";
        case 3:  return n + "rd";
        default: return n + "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost right but upvoted your efforts. Please change "HH" to "hh" for your parser. Else it is okay (although I dare to say that my library [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.Builder.html#addEnglishOrdinal-net.time4j.engine.ChronoElement-) enables a shorter more elegant solution which is also interoperable with Java-8).

Answer (score 3):

Here a shorter Java-8-only solution without an external library:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "MMMM d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter = 
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().append(formatter).toFormatter();
LocalDateTime dateTime = 
  formatter.parse("September 22nd 2015, 10:39:42 am", LocalDateTime::from);
String text = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(dateTime);
System.out.println(text); // 09/22/2015 10:39:42
```

There is only one caveat: The suggested parser might also accept funny inputs like "...22ndst..." etc. but I think this can be neglected here.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 date formats (and essentially you need 2 steps to perform the task) :

1. Parsing the date `September 22nd 2015, 10:39:42 am` using a relevant date format string in order to get/convert it to date object
2. Formatting the date object for your desired `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format to get the date output.

I am leaving the implementation details for you to learn and explore.

[Tutorial for parsing & formatting using the new Date & Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

Comment: Here is the tutorial for parsing and formatting using the new Date & Time API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html