# Unable to parse a Month+day using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, date-parsing, java-time

I tried looking at this link for inspiration: [Parsing a date’s ordinal indicator ( st, nd, rd, th ) in a date-time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514346/parsing-a-date-s-ordinal-indicator-st-nd-rd-th-in-a-date-time-string/28514476#28514476)

However I am getting an error when I try to parse a string "Mon 21st May" to "Monday 21st May" - full day name, date number and full month.

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Mon 21st May' could not be parsed at index 0    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)    at
>   HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:45)

Here is the code:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.Locale;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    String str = "Mon 21st May";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate datetext = LocalDate.parse(str, parseFormatter);

  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the latest code I have tried following suggestions and I changed the string to see if the issue is with that and below is there error I now receive. Looks like it knows the dates, just not able to parse it:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    String str = "Tue 21st May";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate datetext = LocalDate.parse(str, parseFormatter);

  }
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Tue 21st May' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from
>   TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=2, DayOfMonth=21, MonthOfYear=5},ISO of
>   type java.time.format.Parsed  at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
>     at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)    at
>   HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:26) Caused by:
>   java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from
>   TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=2, DayOfMonth=21, MonthOfYear=5},ISO of
>   type java.time.format.Parsed  at
>   java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)  at
>   java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     ... 2 more

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718078/convert-date-with-ordinal-numbers-11th-22nd-etc? Is there something in your case which is not answered in this question?

Comment: The 21 of May is not a Monday. And you need to use EEE, not EEEE.

Comment: You need `EEE`, at most three `E`, for day abbreviation. And you need to supply a year to obtain a `LocalDate`. You should also provide locale.

Comment: I changed it to Tue, still similar issue and I removed the st and still same issue. I will try the locale

Comment: Two of us have pointed out that you have too many `E`. `EEEE` is for full week day name, like `Monday` or `Tuesday`. For the abbreviation you need `E`, `EE` or `EEE`.

Comment: Yeah I changed the EEE as well, sorry forgot to mention that. Let me post and update. I tried adding 2019 year and still issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `MonthDay`

If you want to parse month and day of month without a year, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html):

```
    String str = "Mon 21st May";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse(str, parseFormatter);
    System.out.println(md);
```

Output is:

> --05-21

The leading dash indicates an absent year. `EEEE` in the format pattern string is for full name of the day of week, like Monday or Tuesday. For the abbreviation you need either `E`, `EE` or `EEE`.

## `LocalDate`

If you want a `LocalDate`, you need to supply a year somehow. One option is:

```
    LocalDate datetext = md.atYear(Year.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).getValue());
    System.out.println(datetext);
```

> 2019-05-21

This doesn’t validate the day of month, though. To do that:

```
    String str = "Tue 21st May";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("EEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    LocalDate datetext = LocalDate.parse(str, parseFormatter);
```

> 2019-05-21

In the comment you asked:

> What about if I want to output it as Tuesday 21 May?

It’s sort of a new question and has been covered many times, but OK.

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(datetext.format(outputFormatter));
```

> Tuesday 21 May

### Detecting year from day of week

> I may not know the year, as in I am trying to view dates in an
>   application but some dates may be this year, some may fall over to
>   next year but these dates don't have a year supplied

The following complete example assumes the date falls within the next 3 years from today and detects the year where the day of week is correct. On success it prints in your desired format.

```
    String str = "Wed 20th May";
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    int currentYear = today.getYear();
    LocalDate datetext = null;
    final int maxYearsFromToday = 3;
    for (int year = currentYear; year <= currentYear + maxYearsFromToday; year++) {
        DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("EEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, year)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            datetext = LocalDate.parse(str, parseFormatter);
            System.out.println("Day of week matched for year " + year);
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            // Ignore, try next year
        }
    }

    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    if (datetext == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse date;"
                + " possibly the day of week didn’t match for any year in the range "
                + currentYear + " through " + (currentYear + maxYearsFromToday));
    } else if (datetext.isBefore(today) || datetext.isAfter(today.plusYears(maxYearsFromToday))) {
        System.out.println("Date is out of range");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Successfully parsed: " + datetext.format(outputFormatter));
    }
```

> ```
> Day of week matched for year 2020
> Successfully parsed: Wednesday 20 May
> ```

Comment: What about if I want to output it as Tuesday 21 May?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go a get back to you if it's working

Comment: Can you just provide the full code for the last snippet please, I think I am doing something wrong. Can see you use a format in the alst one and others are parser

Answer (score 1):

It's **Tuesday** 21st May 2019. The code below works.

```
    String str = "Tue 21st May 2019";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate datetext = LocalDate.parse(str, parseFormatter);
```

Comment: Two problems, one it outputs it as Tue 21st May 2019 and not Tuesday 21st May. Second I may not know the year, as in I am trying to view dates in an application but some dates may be this year, some may fall over to next year but these dates don't have a year supplied

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to search for correct year:

Without knowing the day-name of the week, you have a 6/7 chance of parsing the date into the incorrect year.  BUT, if you know the day-name, then you can search a 7 year range to find the correct year.

Assuming you have either a date like one of the following:

```
Wednesday, May 27
WED 5/27
```

And formatters like:

```
DateTimeFormatter visibleButtonFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("EEE M/dd")
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);
        DateTimeFormatter accessibleFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM dd");
```

Then, you can parse a MonthDay like so:

```
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse(dateText, oneOfTheAboveFormatters);
```

Then, you can search for the correct year.  In this case it is 2020:

```
private static int findYearMatchingMonthDay(String dateText, MonthDay monthDay) {
    for(int checkYear = 2020; checkYear >= 2016; checkYear--) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(checkYear, monthDay.getMonth(), monthDay.getDayOfMonth());
        String shortDay = localDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US).toUpperCase();
        if (shortDay.equals(dateText.substring(0,3))) {
            ConsoleUtils.logDebug("Assuming schedule buttons within year: " + checkYear);
            return checkYear;
        }
    }
    return Year.now().getValue();
}
```