# how can we set date in the below formate?

Tags: java

The Date format is   21^st

Actually i written a program to print date in our requirement by using simple Date Format. But I want to print Date in the above formate

welcome to all to solve this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java? (ordinal indicator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatDayOfMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        String s = formatDayOfMonth.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(s);
        int num=Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println(get(num));

    }

    private static String get(int num){
        String[] suffix = {"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};
        int m = num % 100;
       return String.valueOf(num) + suffix[(m > 10 && m < 20) ? 0 : (m % 10)];
    }
}
```