# Unable to parse the French date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to parse some of the French dates in JAVA. Here are some samples.

- 25 septembre 2013 a 21h42 par -- Working
- 1er juillet 2013 a 19h26 par  -- Not Working

Here is the code:

```
Date sampleDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRENCH)
            .parse("25 septembre 2013 a 21h42 par");
    System.out.println(sampleDate);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(sampleDate));
```

I was able to parse successfully (the first date) but not able to parse the second date (1er juillet 2013 a 19h26 par). But If I remove "er" from the date its working. So how can solve this problem.?

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1er juillet 2013 a 19h26 par"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at misc.DateSample.main(DateSample.java:27)
```

Can any one help me on this.?

Thanks & Regards,
Amar.T

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not Spanish.

Also, I only see the code for one of the dates..

Comment: looks like french to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java) Not exactly a perfect duplicate, but the solution do apply

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the letters in the first token:

```
String s = "1er juillet 2013 a 19h26 par";
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
arr[0] = arr[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", "");        
s = String.join(" ", arr);
```

`s` is now:

```
"1 juillet 2013 a 19h26 par"
```

And then use that for your `Date`.