# Date format mismatch. Unparsable exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I  want to change

> "01-Jun-2016 07:54 AM"

to

> "26th May,2016"

**Here is my code**

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat existinFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm aa " , Locale
            .ENGLISH);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String newDateString = "";
Date startDate = null;
try {
    startDate = existinFormat.parse((date));
    newDateString = df.format(startDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but its throws parse exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01-Jun-2016 07:54 AM" (at offset 20)
```

If any one found this solution please share with me.

Comment: Can you use `hh` because `HH` uses 24 hours.

Comment: There are two `a` but only one is needed.

Comment: @BarmanInfo please check answer and specify your resultDateFormat.

Comment: Thanks @WoozyCoder it's working...

Comment: Keep in mind that @KevinWallis is also right. You should replace `HH` for `hh` if you want to use the 12-hour format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
String dateStr = "01-Jun-2016 07:54 AM";
DateFormat existingformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = null;
try {
    date = existingformat.parse(dateStr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (date != null) {
    String resultFormattedDate = newformat.format(date);
    Log.d("resultFormattedDate"," is:"+resultFormattedDate);
}
```

and can you please explain which type of date format is needed to you? I explained here by reference of your code with resultDateFromat is like "MMM dd, yyyy".

Comment: in existingformat dateFormat change a instead of aa. And its working.. Thank you..

Comment: @BarmanInfo Your question "Date format mismatch. Unparsable exception" is solved now. So you can accept my answer and by enhance your question you can achieve "1st Jun, 2016" by using [this reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33540720/5059725) . This link will solve your problem.