# How do I convert dateformat from Date to April 19th or April 22nd

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert the date object into String. For example,

Date date = ......... ;

date.toString shows something like Wed April 17  00:00:00.0 CEST 2016"

and I want to display as only April 17th, removing extra informations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/164/date-class/633/converting-date-to-a-certain-string-format#t=201607251439489136276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String strDate = new SimpleDatFormat("MMM dd").format(date);
```

as for st/rd/th you will need to add it manually, e.g. by doing if and appending those to the `strDate`.