# How to get ordinal indicators (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc) in Go

Tags: datetime, go, time, format, ordinal

Go's `time` package lets me do this:

```golang
time.Now().Format("2 January 2006")
```

which returns something like `10 November 2009`.

Can I get something like `10th November 2009` using `time` or any standard Go package?

The [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) documentation doesn't mention it, and I'd like to avoid [doing it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-ordinal) if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize/blob/master/ordinals.go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for that in the built-in `time` library. You'll either need to implement the functionality yourself, using an algorithm as described in the linked Java question, or use a third-party library which can do it for you, such as `humanize`: https://godoc.org/github.com/dustin/go-humanize#Ordinal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as pretty as it could be but you could use this:

```
func GetOrdinalNumber(n int) string {
    func GetOrdinalNumber(n int) string {
    if n >= 11 && n <= 13 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dth", n)
    }

    switch n % 10 {
    case 1:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dst", n)
    case 2:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dnd", n)
    case 3:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%drd", n)
    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dth", n)
    }
}
```