# How to add day suffix[st,nd,rd,th] in timestamp's date in ffmpeg command?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using this command to add time stamp in video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%d %b, %Y %I\\\:%M %p}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

this command generate date & time: `05 Dec, 2019 06:21 AM`

but i want to add day suffix after day in date like this : `05th Dec, 2019 06:21 AM`

//like 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th.... etc

what changes i have to do to achieve this?

Comment: [My modern answer to the suggested original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369812/5772882) requires that you *either* code for Android API level 26 or higher *or* you use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). In the latter case add that library to your Android project and make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages. [The long explanation is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: i want ffmpeg command not java code bro

Comment: It will help me partially i don't get satisfied solution

Comment: i put bounty on this question for 7 days no one is answering and last day someone is ans and i get little help or you can say little help so i accepted as ans

Comment: and also your ans come after that also i updated my code with your ans

Answer (score 0):

you can format your date before you call ffmpeg command

```
private String addExtention(String format) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String df[] = format.split("th");
    String result;
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat(df[0], Locale.getDefault());
    result = df1.format(c.getTime());
    char lastChar = result.charAt(result.length() - 1);
    char secondlastChar = result.charAt(result.length() - 2);

    Log.e("::MG::", "addExtention: " + lastChar);
    Log.e("::MG::", "addExtention: " + secondlastChar);
    if (lastChar == '1' && (secondlastChar == '0' || secondlastChar == '2' || secondlastChar == '3'))
        result += "st";
    else if (lastChar == '2' && (secondlastChar == '0' || secondlastChar == '2'))
        result += "nd";
    else if (lastChar == '3' && (secondlastChar == '0' || secondlastChar == '2'))
        result += "rd";
    else
        result += "th";

    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(df[1], Locale.getDefault());
    result += df2.format(c.getTime());
    return result;
}
```

// Call Function

```
String strDate=addExtention("05 Dec, 2019 06:21 AM");
```

now you can pass `strDate` to `ffmpeg` command

Comment: This ans is not perfect but it helped me lot.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).