# How to get the ordinal indicator using time.Format()?

Tags: go

The `time.Format()` method will parse the argument `January 2, 2006` into outputting `June 20, 2021`, but it won't parse `January 2nd, 2006` into `June 20th, 2021` and instead output `June 20nd, 2021`.

How could I tell it to use the right ordinal indiciator: `st`/`nd`/`rd`/`th` suffix? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the ordinal indicator is not there in the standard library. You can either implement the same yourself by taking help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011232/5821408) or use a third-party package.

There is a third-party package available for Go to convert the input integer to a string with the correct ordinal indicator; take a look at [go-humanize](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dustin/go-humanize?utm_source=godoc#Ordinal).

Also, if you look under the hood at the implementation of go-humanize's support for the ordinal indicator; you'd notice that is very simple so I'd prefer maybe just implement it yourself by referring to both implementations I have linked. Refer: https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize/blob/v1.0.0/ordinals.go#L8

Or, go use go-humanize.

Answer (score 1):

To add right ordinal indicator: `st/nd/rd/th` suffix you can make use of `switch case` .I have created a sample program to print all days of month along with their respective suffixes as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func getDaySuffix(n int) string {

    if n >= 11 && n <= 13 {
        return "th"
    } else {

        switch n % 10 {
        case 1:
            return "st"
        case 2:
            return "nd"
        case 3:
            return "rd"
        default:
            return "th"
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    for i := 1; i < 32; i++ {
        suf := getDaySuffix(i)
        fmt.Println(i, suf)

    }

}
```

Output:

```
1 st
2 nd
3 rd
4 th
5 th
6 th
7 th
8 th
9 th
10 th
11 th
12 th
13 th
14 th
15 th
16 th
17 th
18 th
19 th
20 th
21 st
22 nd
23 rd
24 th
25 th
26 th
27 th
28 th
29 th
30 th
31 st
```